# removing date and extention from url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently changed the permalink format of my blog so the date and extention .php is removed:
ago:
http://domain.com/2014/09/-cc-tenton-photoshop-cc-for-the-web.php
after:
http://domain.com/-cc-tenton-photoshop-cc-for-the-web

now i want redirect old link to new link with htaccess and 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as **very first rule** in your wordpress `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.+?)\.php$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```